# Dont know how to populate Mongoose Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a problem with a mongoose population and I don't know what I should do.

I got two schemas:

```
var userSchema =  new userSchema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    mods: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'}]
});
var dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true}
});
```

So one user can have several data packages.
Some users are moderated by other users.

Whats the query for a moderator, that all his own data packages and the ones of the users he is moderating are listed?

You see that I have a SQL background and there's definitely another way to do it with MongoDB.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear understand what queries do you need but first you need set ref property in 'owner' field in dataSchema. As about population it's look like this:

```
//if you use callback
users.find({/*your query*/}).populate('mods')
.exec((err, result)=>{/*your code*/});

//if you use promise
users.find({/*your query*/}).populate('mods').exec()
.then(result=>{/*your code*/})
.catch(err=>{throw err});
```

Comment: Here's an example: I got three users user1, user2 and user3. user1 is a moderator of user2. All users have their own data stuff in the database. Now I need the query that user1 gets his own data AND the data of user2 (because he's the moderator of him).